# Remove dynamically added comboboxes in #C

Tags: c#, winforms

I have encountered a problem that I just can not find a solution!

I have this script that dynamically adds a `ComboBox` when a button is pressed.

Now I would really like to have the option to delete the last added `ComboBox` again.

I have a counter `c` that counts how many `ComboBox`es have been added so immediately, it should not be a problem, I just can not figure out how!

Anyone can come up with some nice ideas?

```
int c = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

ComboBox cboRun = new ComboBox();
cboRun.Name = "cboDynamic" + c++;
cboRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * c));
cboRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
this.Controls.Add();
```

What code should I use to remove this added `ComboBox`?

I have tried something like

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Controls.Remove("cboDynamic" + c.ToString());
}
```

but without success.

Comment: I edited to replace the `WPF` tag with `winforms` tag. If there is some misunderstanding here (such as you posted the wrong code not added a wrong tag), please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RemoveByKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of just `Remove`:

```
this.Controls.RemoveByKey("cboDynamic" + c.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Controls.RemoveAt(this.Controls.Count - 1);
```

Will remove the **last** control that you added.

Comment: I'm not convinced this solution would work 100% of the time under certain scenarios

Comment: I don't think any solution will work 100% of the time under certain scenarios. That's why we developers have jobs, so that when something doesn't work, we get to coding and making them work :)

Comment: lol true. What I mean though is, this will remove the last control added. But then what if, down the road, another programmer comes in and needs to create some new dynamically created control after these comboboxes are dynamically created. This will lead to some inevitable head scratching when their new controls suddenly start vanishing for no "apparent reason".

Answer (score 0):

In your button2_Click() method, you are trying to remove the control by name. You need to use the actual control object in order to remove it from the Controls collection.

Try something like the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var comboBox in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList())
    {
        if (comboBox.Name.Equals("cboDynamic" + c.ToString()))
            this.Controls.Remove(comboBox); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will result in a runtime exception - you're modifying the list you're iterating over inside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Controls.Remove() takes a control object... not it's ID.

Here's a way to do it, and it will work no matter what other dynamic controls are latter added.  In essence, we simply keep a Stack FIFO of the comboboxes, pushing when added, and popping when removed.

```
private Stack<ComboBox> dynamicBoxes = new Stack<ComboBox>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ComboBox cboRun = new ComboBox();
    cboRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * c));
    cboRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
    dynamicBoxes.Push(cboRun);
    this.Controls.Add(cboRun);     
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
    var lastComboBox = dynamicBoxes.Pop();
    Controls.Remove(lastComboBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RemoveByKey and rest 1 to the c var because at that moment the value is already increased and the control name is different.

```
Controls.RemoveByKey("cboDynamic" + (c-1).ToString());
```

Greetings